# pagetitle from linq result

Tags: windows-phone-7

how could i bind my pagetitle to a linq result? if i have this code:

```
    var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("article")
                   select new article
                   {
                       Title = (string)query.Element("title").Value,
                       SubTitle = (string)query.Element("subtitle").Value,
                       Content = (string)query.Element("content").Value
                   };
```

if i use:

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="    {StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Foreground="White" />
```

it doesnt work? :|

Comment: How do you expect this to work at all? Either you're leaving out a lot (DataContext, ViewModel, the Title property, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, etc.) or I don't see how this would work at all.